# iOS TableView : Why the content of UITableViewCell is not getting refresh it's autolayout based on content?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am preparing layout for the listing of various posts
In that case i have design layout for type image with text in separate .xib file named `"ImageCell"` and i have also registered it in `viewDidLoad()` method
In result it shows full content but the issue is with rendering the layout
Case :
If we upload a image like in rectangle shape it shows initially to the square image in listing but,
Only after scrolling it's only taking full height for that particular `"ImageCell"`

For more explanation i am providing here code snippet

**`"ImageCell" class`**

```
class ImageCell: UITableViewCell {
        //MARK: - Properties
        @IBOutlet weak var lblUserName: NBLabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var imgProfile: UIImageView! {
            didSet{
              imgProfile.layer.cornerRadius = imgProfile.frame.size.height / 2
              imgProfile.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var imgFeedBG: ScaledHeightImageView!

        static let identifier = "ImageCell"
        override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()
        }
        
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            if self.imgFeedBG != nil {
                 self.imgFeedBG.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            }
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.needsUpdateConstraints()
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
         }
       }
       override func prepareForReuse() {
           self.lblDesc.text = nil
           self.imgFeedBG.image = nil
           super.prepareForReuse()
       }
       func setupWithItem(_ dict: PostElement) {
            let feedImageUrl = dict.imageURL.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
            self.imgFeedBG.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.whiteLarge
        }


}
```

**ViewController class**

```
class PostVC: UIViewController {
     
      @IBOutlet weak var tableViewPosts: UITableView!
      var arrData = [PostElement]()
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          self.tableViewPosts.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
          self.tableViewPosts.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
                  tableViewPosts?.register(UINib(nibName: ImageCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: ImageCellidentifier)
           self.tableViewPosts.delegate = self
           self.tableViewPosts.dataSource = self
      }
      override func viewDidAppear(_ animated : Bool) {
          super.viewDidAppear(animated)
          /*
          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
              self.tableViewPosts.beginUpdates()
              self.tableViewPosts.setNeedsDisplay()
              self.tableViewPosts.endUpdates()
          })
          */
          UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
             self.tableViewPosts.beginUpdates()
             self.tableViewPosts.reloadData()
             self.tableViewPosts.endUpdates()
          }
     }
    



}


class PostVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ImageCell.identifier) as? ImageCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.setupWithItem(dict)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                    cell.setNeedsLayout()
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
            return cell
     }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat  {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100 // UITableView.automaticDimension
     }
 }
```

For more explanation kindly check the pictures

1. Xib design

   [image: Xib]
2. Current wrong layout results

   [image: Current Result Layout even we are uploading square image]

As we can see in second image the current result shows the square even if we upload the image in rectangle

Kindly help me to solve this stuff?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're going to run into a lot of problems trying to do this. When a cell changes its own height, you need to tell the tableview to update to reflect that. If you are async downloading images for each cell, and then changing the image view height (which changes the cell height), and then updating the table... you'll get a lot of "jumping." Depending on how many images (rows) you'll have, you'd be better off downloading all the images and *then* updating the table. If you have lots and lots of rows, you probably want to pick a height and use `.scaleAspectFit`

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
             cell.setNeedsLayout()
             cell.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
}`

As per the below code exists in `cellForRow` method if we add this below snippet inside `tableView.beginUpdate()` and `tableView.endUpdate()` it seems stuck the UI because it's performing for every cell's so 
I am finding the alternative for this 


Kindly help me on this

Comment: You need to review the SDWebImage docs and look at the completion blocks. *After* the image has finished downloading and will be set in the image view, you need to tell the table view to re-calculate the cell height(s). You're not going to have much luck just throwing a bunch of `beginUpdate() / endUpdate()` code in there.